# Дописывать строки в файл CSV php

Tags: php, csv

Этот код почему-то удаляет все данные из файла и записывает новые при каждом вызове saveRow().

$list - одномерный массив...

```
function saveRow($list) {
    $base = 'base.csv';
    if (is_writable($base)) {
        if (!$handle = fopen($base, 'a')) {
            $list = array_map("utf8_decode", $list);
            fputcsv($handle, $list);
            fclose($handle);
        }
    }
}
```

Как дописывать строки в csv файл?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно вынести `fopen` и `fclose` за пределы цикла, вызывающего эту функцию.

**UPDATE**

Согласно [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fputcsv.php), "Указатель на файл должен быть корректным и указывать на файл, успешно открытый функциями fopen() или fsockopen() (и все еще не закрытым функцией fclose())."

По всей видимости, ваш код выглядит примерно так:

```
function saveRow($list) {
    $base = 'base.csv';
    if (is_writable($base)) {
        if (!$handle = fopen($base, 'a')) {
            $list = array_map("utf8_decode", $list);
            fputcsv($handle, $list);
            fclose($handle);
        }
    }
}

funcion xxx() {
    foreach () {
    //...
        saveRow($list);
    // ...
}
```

Надо сделать так

```
function saveRow($list, $handle) {
            $list = array_map("utf8_decode", $list);
            fputcsv($handle, $list);
}

funcion xxx() {
    $base = 'base.csv';
    if (is_writable($base)) {
        if (!$handle = fopen($base, 'a')) {
            foreach () {
            //...
                saveRow($list, $handle);
            // ...
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание на изменения в функции saveRow.

Comment: А можете написать более подробный ответ?

Comment: А как его написать, если я не вижу цикла, в котором вызывается saveRow?

Comment: Так оставьте об этом комментарий, чтобы автор догадался. Получите подробности и ответьте более полно. В текущем виде ваш ответ больше похож на комментарий, чем на полноценный ответ.

Comment: Я понял о чем писал KAGG Design, но это не помогает, наверное проблема в php сервере.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov  я дополнил ответ

Comment: KAGG Design, благодарю за попытку...

Comment: @SergeySereda Тогда обновите вопрос, добавьте новые подробности. Поделитесь другими фрагментами кода, которые могут вызывать нежелательное поведение и т.д.

Comment: Помогла замена php.ini (наверное, я там что-то случайно подтер). Кстати, я перепроверил: открытие и закрытие файла на каждом шаге цикла - работает...

Comment: Не понимаю, почему РНРшники не сделают себе GUI, а то в 21 веке, копаться в конфигах PHP и Апатча - настоящее извращение.

Answer (score 2):

Вот рабочий код, надо ему посылать массив

```
function saveRow($list) {
  $file = fopen("base.csv","a");
  foreach ($list as $line)
  {
    fputcsv($file,explode(',',$line));
  }
  fclose($file); 
}
saveRow(Array("test,test"));
```

Comment: Благодарю!         ...................